# HP Laptop won't boot windows 10 installation usb

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation

Hello I can't boot windows 10 installation USB on HP Laptop 15-rb0xx.

I tried everything and will be glad for any help.

Unix Gparted boot well.

[Screen after I boot from flash. It stucks here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AurCA.jpg)

Comment: Does your laptop have a CD tray? If it does, try burning the ISO to a CD instead of a USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firmware BIOS update helped. Hold Win+B + power key 5 sec then Win+B next 15 sec and then release to update BIOS when you dont see Firmware management.

Comment: That DID solve it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that doing a BIOS recovery to the latest BIOS fixes this annoying problem. Laptop was on BIOS version 13 and would not play ball with windows 10 install media. BIOS version 55 fixed all compatibility issues with Win10

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓, in this case self answered) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).